# Polyhedrons and spheres/ surface and and solids

Tags: geometry

Each edge of a regular tetrahedron has length e. Show that the altitude of the tetrahedron is the measure of h=radical 6/3×e  how do I solve for this problem help! [image]
I know it's a 90 60 30 triangle but I don't know how to solve for it

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABC$ be the "basis", $V$ be the "vertex", $VO$ be the height of the tetrahedron and $VH$ be the height o the face $VBC$. You know that $VO\perp OH$ and you should know by the theorems you've studied that $OH$ is the segment that connects the center of $ABC$ to the mid point of $BC$. So, in particular, $OH=\frac13 AH=\frac13 VH$. You know the length of $VH$ in terms of $e$, (as you said, $VHB$ is a $90/30/60$ triangle) therefore you can use Pythagoras' theorem on $VHO$.

**By the way:** Why polihedra and *spheres*?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Diagram]

Consider this image of a (black) tetrahedron. We know it has side length $e$.

The red triangle is a right triangle that connects the foot of the altitude from one point to two vertices. We know that the foot of the altitude lies on the centroid of the face of the tetrahedron, so the leg contained in that face is precisely

$$\frac{2}{3}e\text{.}$$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html

We know the hypotenuse (spoiler alert: it's $e$), so to find the altitude's length, we can use the Pythagorean theorem.

Do you see how to continue from here?

Comment: I don't know how to show how h= radical 6/3 e I'm lost

Comment: @EdithMendoza Well, since the red-colored triangle is a right triangle, we know that $h=\sqrt{e^2-(2e/3)^2}$. You can simplify that expression to your desired one. ($h$ is the length of one of the legs of the triangle, $2e/3$ is another leg, and $e$ is the hypotenuse.)